# Changing row font color of rows with vuejs and veuntify

Tags: vue.js

I need to change the row font color of a vuetify v-data-table.

I receive from my backend a set of rows and each row has a column called "color_status".

I have created a template to do it. But, the problem is that when executed it shows all fields.

I´d like to show only the fields of the header.

Is there a simple way to do it?

```
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="fila"
      :options.sync="options"
      :server-items-length="total"
      :loading="loading"
      sort-by="nome"
      :items-per-page="5"
      :search="search"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <tr :style="{ color: getColorStatus(item) }">
          <td v-for="key in Object.keys(item)" :key="key">
            {{ item[key] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.ativo="{ item }">
        <v-icon color="success">
          {{
            item.ativo.trim() == "T"
              ? "mdi-checkbox-marked"
              : "mdi-checkbox-blank-outline"
          }}
        </v-icon>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="restart">Reiniciar</v-btn>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:item.nome="{ item }">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'EditFila', params: { id: item.id } }">{{
          item.nome
        }}</router-link>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>

methods:{
    getColorStatus(item) {
      return item.color_status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop through `headers` instead of `Objects` ?

`<td v-for="key in headers" :key="key">
   {{ item[key] }}
</td>`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Please add more details as to what is not working. If possible add a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link which will help to debug

Comment: Hi, used: <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <tr :style="{ color: getColorStatus(item) }">
          <td v-for="key in Object.keys(headers)" :key="key">
            {{ item[headers[key].value] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.horaent="{ item }">
        <span>{{ new Date(item.horaent).toLocaleString() }}</span>
      </template>

Comment: But, The rows change the color. But I have a colateral effect: the next template formatting the datetime column stops to works. It shows the date time in as "2015-03-25T12:00:00Z"